# Derivatives of Harmonic Functions converge normally?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $h_{n}$ be a sequence of harmonic functions that converge normally
to $h$. Prove that $h_{n}'\rightarrow h'$ normally.

Certainly, this theorem holds when we have analytic functions (using
Cauchy estimates). But how to generalize from here, using that every
harmonic function is locally the real part of an analytic function, or Poisson integral...?

Comment: [All harmonic functions are analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Remarks).

Comment: Harmonic functions satisfy Cauchy estimates, almost by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Harmonic functions also satisfy Cauchy estimates. There are various ways of proving this. One way is to use the mean value property: Let $\phi(x,y)$ be a radial function with integral $1$, and let $\phi_R(x,y) = R^2\phi(Rx,Ry)$. Then 
$$u \ast \phi_R(x,y) = R^2\int u(x - X,y - Y)\phi(Rx,Ry)\,dX\,dY$$
Converting this integral into polar coordinates the using the mean value property for a fixed radius will give that 
$$u \ast \phi_R(x,y) = u(x,y)$$
Then differentiating under the integral sign gives
$$(u \ast \partial^{\alpha} \phi_R)(x,y) = \partial^{\alpha}u(x,y)$$
Bounding $\partial^{\alpha} \phi_R$ and integrating gives the Cauchy estimates. (I'm not writing every step due to time constraints). One thing worth pointing out here is that this argument works for higher derivatives too, as well as harmonic functions in $n$ dimensions for $n > 2$.